# How to create a randomized if else statement swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, if-statement, random, swift3

The following code runs like a traffic light. Red -> Yellow -> Green. How can my code by written so that when "else if timerInt == 0 {" comes either r.png or yellow.png come up. Basically a coin is flipped and either r or yellow will show up. But the chances are equal and its always random. Thanks

```
   timerInt -= 1
    if timerInt == 2{
        light.image = UIImage(named: "r.png")
    } else if timerInt == 1 {
        light.image = UIImage(named: "yellow.png")
    } else if timerInt == 0 {
        light.image = UIImage(named: "g.png")
     }
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to add another condition within the `if timerInt == 0` block. This if statement will use [`arc4random_uniform(upperBound)`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/arc4random), which generates a random number between 0 and `upperBound`

```
light.image = UIImage(named: arc4random_uniform(2) == 0 ? "r.png" : "yellow.png")
```

---

here, I inlined the if statement using a ternary operator. If the condition is met, the first expression will be evaluated, otherwise it'll be the later.

Comment: I would write this as: `light.image = UIImage(named: arc4random_uniform(2) == 0 ? "r" : "yellow")`

Comment: ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ in production code, I'd certainly have those images in a resource namespace, so more likely `light.image = arc4random_uniform(2) == 0 ? Resource.Image.redLight : Resource.Image.yellowLight`. But yeah, here it probably makes sense.